# What are "flaps" and what do they do

Tags: world-of-warplanes

In World of Warplanes the default keybinding 'E' is set to "use flaps", when trying to use flaps on the T1 planes(biplanes), it simply says "you don't have any", but on higher tier planes (most of the single wings from what I gather), nothing happens. Speed doesn't change much, maneuverability doesn't seem to get any better, either.

So my question is what do flaps actually do, are they more effective at higher tiers?

[kind of related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120583/what-do-the-combat-flaps-do) but different game entirely. so it's rules/physics may not apply

Comment: IRL, flaps improve lift and are used to allow the plane to fly at lower speeds without stalling, especially during takeoff and landing.  In most video games, they reduce the stall speed and increase the drag, though in some they decrease your turning radius.  I'm unsure how they are implemented in this specific video game, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing for a weekend with different planes. I can say now with certainty that flaps act as airbrakes and improve your turning radius. the amount it improves depends on the plane (heavy fighters seem to benefit more)

In fact I've developed a strategy to use by turning off engine and activating flips while climbing to basically stop the climb immediately and start falling into a very tight loop. helps when being chased and the enemy doesn't know about flaps.

Answer (score 0):

From the [great Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flap_%28aircraft%29):

> Flaps are devices used to improve the lift characteristics of a wing
>   and are mounted on the trailing edges of the wings of a fixed-wing
>   aircraft to reduce the speed at which the aircraft can be safely flown
>   and to increase the angle of descent for landing. They shorten takeoff
>   and landing distances. Flaps do this by lowering the stall speed and
>   increasing the drag.

What this means for the game is: effectively not much.

They're super handy for landing.  For example, your stall speed is much lower so you're less likely to run out of runway while you fiddle with your descent rate (i.e., you have more time to plan and react).  If you're just flying for the shoot-em-up dogfights (i.e., fly until you die), this won't be much of a factor.

They're marginally useful for ground-attack since, again, you'll have more time to plan your run.

If you're fighting faster aircraft, you might find the the additional maneuverability at low speed keeps you alive longer.